# Programmatically/dynamically remove required property

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, typescript1.8

I have the following

```
<md-input required
          placeholder = "Race"
          [(ngModel)] = "rase.race"
          formControlName = "race"></md-input>
```

Is there a way to remove the required property dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: This is currently not supported. You can use a conditional (custom) validator. Actually you can using binding for the property but then the validator wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. Just could not find anything on it.

Comment: There are lots of related issues in GitHub repo.